# JavaFx 2 - Combobox rendering color choice

Tags: colors, combobox, javafx-2

I have a

```
ComboBox cmb = new ComboBox();
```

I would like to display a list of colors, if possible ordered from brighter to darkest, but I haven't find any working example

How to render a combobox in order to display a list of color?

Any help really appreciated

Thanks

**Edit:** question closed, solved by myself, thanks all.

Comment: Alberto, you are a developer working with JavaFX for quite a long time. Please provide your coding effort, investigation on the net, other stuff. See these links for reference: [example of color patterns for listview (the same semantics are also valid for combobox)](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/list-view.htm#CEGIIDDC) and [Combo-box key value pair in JavaFX 2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10699655). Try to combine these two tutorials. If you stuck somewhere then update your question accordingly. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

To calculate brightness (for sorting) use the luminosity coefficients:

```
var color = Color.FromArgb(240,230,210); // use whatever color you're wanting to rank
var luminosity = 0.299*color.R + 0.587*color.G+ 0.114*color.B;
```

As for rendering it into a combobox, I know it can't be done with the standard Window Forms Combobox. But, it wouldn't be too hard to make your own ComboBox control. I would guess you could do it pretty readily in WPF. As for the approach to take - you'll need to generate a graphics object and draw rectangles of the color onto the control - or draw to an in-memory bitmap and set a picturebox's image property to that image. Good luck!

Comment: thanks for your reply, but as from my tags, the question is about JavaFx 2 ComboBox

Comment: woopsy =) sorry I just assumed it was .NET framework stuff. Same principles apply, though I'm not familiar with controls in javafx