# Customize ListView in JavaFX with FXML

Tags: javafx, fxml

I want to make a customize list view in javafx. Here I need to bind multiple component in list cell as follow, like 
one label, one textfield, one button under one HBox and
two button, one hyperlink, one label in another HBox and 
these HBox comes under one VBox and 
this VBox comes under the single list cell and 
it will repeat and make a list View.

The code is

```
<ListView fx:id="ListView" layoutX="0" layoutY="30" prefWidth="600" prefHeight="300">
    <HBox fx:id="listBox" alignment="CENTER_LEFT">
        <padding><Insets top="5" bottom="5" left="5"></Insets> </padding>
        <HBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT" prefWidth="170" minWidth="88">
            <Label fx:id="surveyName" text="Field A" styleClass="Name"></Label>
        </HBox>
        <VBox styleClass="Description" prefWidth="155" minWidth="86">

            <HBox>
                <HBox styleClass="surveyDesIcon" prefWidth="20" prefHeight="16"></HBox>
                <Label fx:id="surveyCode" text="PRW3456HJ"></Label>
            </HBox>
            <HBox>
                <HBox styleClass="DateIcon" prefWidth="20" prefHeight="16"></HBox>
                <Label fx:id="Date" text="PRW3456HJ"></Label>
            </HBox>
        </VBox>
        <HBox fx:id="Status" prefWidth="160" minWidth="80">
            <Label fx:id="StatusLabel" text="Checking Files.."/>
        </HBox>
        <HBox fx:id="StatusIcon1" prefWidth="50" prefHeight="50" alignment="CENTER">
            <Label styleClass="StatusIcon1" prefWidth="24" prefHeight="24" alignment="CENTER"/>
        </HBox>
        <HBox fx:id="StatusIcon2" prefWidth="50" prefHeight="50" styleClass="StatusIconBox" alignment="CENTER">
            <Hyperlink styleClass="StatusIcon2" prefWidth="24" maxHeight="24" alignment="CENTER"/>
        </HBox>
    </HBox>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Have you tried cell factory for listview? See http://stackoverflow.com/a/10700642.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

I understand your question. There are mainly two ways to set items in a `Listview`:

**1.** Create the `ObservableList` and set the items of the `ListView` with the `ObservableList` (`listView.setItems(observableList)`).

**2.** Use the `setCellFactory()` method of the `ListView` class.

You would prefer to use the `setCellFactory()` method, because this approach simplies the process as well as it helps to separate out the business logic and the UI (FXML).

---

**Here is a more detailed explaination:**

---

**1.** Create a new FXML file with the name `listview.fxml` to contain the `ListView`, and set the `ListViewController` class as its controller:

File: *listview.fxml*:

```
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import demo.ListViewController?>

<GridPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="CENTER">
     <ListView fx:id="listView"/>
</GridPane>
```

---

**2.** Create the controller and name it `ListViewController`.
The controller can load the `listview.fxml` file and access the `listview`.

File: *ListViewController.java*:

```
package demo;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.util.Callback;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Set;

public class ListViewController
{
    @FXML
    private ListView listView;
    private Set<String> stringSet;
    ObservableList observableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public ListViewController()
    {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/listview.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);
        try
        {
            Parent parent = (Parent)fxmlLoader.load();
            Scene scene = new Scene(parent, 400.0 ,500.0);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public void setListView()
    {
        stringSet.add("String 1");
        stringSet.add("String 2");
        stringSet.add("String 3");
        stringSet.add("String 4");
        observableList.setAll(stringSet);
        listView.setItems(observableList);
        listView.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<String>, javafx.scene.control.ListCell<String>>()
        {
            @Override
            public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> listView)
            {
                return new ListViewCell();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

**3.** First you need to set the value of the `ObservableList`. **This is very important.**
Then, set the items of list using the `ObservableList` and call the `setCellFactory()` method on the `ListView`. In the given example I just take the `String` values an add them to the `String` set (the `Set<String> stringSet`).

---

**4.** When the `setCellFactory()` method is called on the `ListView`, it will return the `ListCell`. So for sake of simplicity, I added a class which extends the `ListCell`, and the `setGraphic()` method is present for the `ListCell()` and will set the items of the `ListCell`.

File: *ListViewCell.java*:

```
package demo;

import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;

public class ListViewCell extends ListCell<String>
{
    @Override
    public void updateItem(String string, boolean empty)
    {
        super.updateItem(string,empty);
        if(string != null)
        {
            Data data = new Data();
            data.setInfo(string);
            setGraphic(data.getBox());
        }
    }
}
```

---

**5.** I just added a class which will load the `listCellItem.fxml` and return the `HBox`, which will contain the other components as children.
The `HBox` is then set to the `ListCell`.

File: *listCellItem.fxml*:

```
 <?import demo.Data?>
 <?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
 <?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>

<HBox xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:id="hBox">
<children>
    <Label  fx:id="label1"/>
    <Label  fx:id="label2"/>
</children>
</HBox>
```

File: *Data.java*:

```
package demo;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Data
{
    @FXML
    private HBox hBox;
    @FXML
    private Label label1;
    @FXML
    private Label label2;

    public Data()
    {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/listCellItem.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);
        try
        {
            fxmlLoader.load();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public void setInfo(String string)
    {
        label1.setText(string);
        label2.setText(string);
    }

    public HBox getBox()
    {
        return hBox;
    }
}
```

---

Using this way, you can use the `setCellFactory()` method to separate the things that are business logic and FXML.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: This answer best suits for the javafx application which is designed on MVC.

Comment: Hey thanks Anvay, I was expecting exactly the same component as you mention here. Thanks a lot

Comment: The best answer I have ever read! MVC pattern is nice! Using JavaFX as a master!

Comment: This really works. Although there's a problem using the updateItem on the listcell class. You shouldn't be "inflating" the FXML everytime that method is called. Consider creating a Data object in the constructor of the ListCell and only update its content on the updateItem method. (inflating only once)

Comment: How to add new item in custom listview at runtime??

Comment: I guess  `fxmlLoader.load();` should be replaced by `hBox = fxmlLoader.load();`

Comment: very old QA .. but: bullet 4 is fundamentally wrong (and probably already was at the time of posting) - you __must not__ create the ui in updateItem (because cells are reused), instead load it once in the constructor and only configure in updateItem. Also note, that the cell must be unconfigured if empty or null item

Answer (score 6):

The example above by @**Anvay** needs a couple of tweaks to work.  These are simple things to set on-track.

1. The ListViewController needs to be running on the JavaFX application thread.
2. You can only call the injected @FXML elements from the JavaFX **initialize**() method
3. Need to call setListView()
4. The stringSet in the example needs to be allocated with a new before calling setListView().

The ListViewController below works with these changes.  I changed "*stringSet*" to a list, "*stringList*".  The controller is pretty much the sample controller provided by **Scene Builder** 2

```
 public class ListViewController 
 {

     @FXML private   ResourceBundle      resources;

     @FXML private   URL                 location;

     @FXML private   ListView            listView;

     private         List<String>        stringList     = new ArrayList<>(5);
     private         ObservableList      observableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

     public void setListView(){

         stringList.add("String 1");
         stringList.add("String 2");
         stringList.add("String 3");
         stringList.add("String 4");

         observableList.setAll(stringList);

         listView.setItems(observableList);

         listView.setCellFactory(
             new Callback<ListView<String>, javafx.scene.control.ListCell<String>>() {
                 @Override
                 public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> listView) {
                     return new ListViewCell();
                 }
             });
     }

     @FXML
     void initialize() {
         assert listView != null : "fx:id=\"listView\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'CustomList.fxml'.";

         setListView();
     }

 }//ListViewController
```

The JavaFX platform needs to be started in the main() method from a JavaFX Application.   Netbeans conviently provides most of this structure from the Maven JavaFX application template.

```
public class MainApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/CustomList.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("/styles/Styles.css");

        stage.setTitle("CustomList");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     *  The main() method is ignored in correctly deployed JavaFX application.
     * 
     *  @param args the command line arguments
     **/
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer by Anvay for some reason didnt work for me, what i had to do to fix it was just some very small tweaks:

1. remove import data statement from listCellItem.fxml
2. as the comment below the post states in Data.java put hBox = fmxlLoader.load()
3. I also had a main class (intellij auto generated).

   ```
   public class MainMain extends Application {

   @Override
   public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

   FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new 
   FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("MainController.fxml"));
   try
   {
       Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();

       Scene scene = new Scene(root);
       primaryStage.setScene(scene);
       primaryStage.setTitle("Title");
       primaryStage.show();
   }
   catch (IOException e)
   {
       throw new RuntimeException(e);
   }
   }



   public static void main(String[] args) {
       launch(args);
   }
   ```

I know this was probably obvious for most of the experts here, but these issues perplexed me for hours while i was debugging.