# JavaFX ListCell enable horizontal Growth

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I currently have a ListView that is resizable in Width and I use a custom CellFactory that returns my custom ListCell objects.

I already read this:
[Customize ListView in JavaFX with FXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19588029/customize-listview-in-javafx-with-fxml) and I use a similar construct like the one mentioned:

```
public class ListViewCell extends ListCell<String>{
@Override
public void updateItem(String string, boolean empty){
    super.updateItem(string,empty);
    if(string != null) {
        ...
        setGraphic(myComponent);
    }
}
```

I want `myComponent` to take the full size that is available inside the ListCell, however it seems that the `setGraphic` method limits the size of the given Node.

I can provide all my code if it is necessary, however I am not sure which parts are relevant and I do not want to post a big wall of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my Problem now, here is how:

```
class MyListCell extends ListCell<MyObject>
{
    private final AnchorPane _myComponent;

    public MyListCell()
    {
        ...
        this.setPrefWidth(0);
        myComponent.prefWidthProperty().bind(this.widthProperty());
    }

    ...

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(MyObject item, boolean empty)
    {
        ...
        setGraphic(_myComponent);
        ...
    }
}
```

If `this.setPrefWdith(0)` is ommited, myComponent will grow inside the ListCell, but the Cell won't shrink if I shrink my ListView.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `prefWidth` property of your control to `Infinity` either via CSS or via API so as to provide its maximal expansion whithin container:

```
myComponent.setStyle("-fx-pref-width: Infinity");
```

Comment: I tried `myComponent.prefWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);`, however this had no visible Effect.