# JavaFX Custom ListCell HGrow

Tags: javafx, gridpane

I have a ListView with a custom ListCellFactory. In my CustomListCell implemenation I use setGraphic to set the list item graphic to a GridPane but I am not able not let the GridPane fill the whole width of the ListView. The following is a short version of my code:

```
class MyListCell extends ListCell<MyObject>
{
    private final GridPane _myComponent;

    public MyListCell()
    {
        ...
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY); // does not help
        //this.setPrefWidth(0); // does not help
        myComponent.prefWidthProperty().bind(this.widthProperty()); // does not help
    }

    ...

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(MyObject item, boolean empty)
    {
        ...
        setGraphic(_myComponent);
        ...
    }
}
```

Even with the prefWidth bounding from [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108466/javafx-listcell-enable-horizontal-growth) my GridPane will not grow! No matter what combination of layout constraints I use it looks as follows:

[Example View](http://fs2.directupload.net/images/150110/owrjcqfd.png)

The GridPane shall expand to the full width of the ListCell (I want to add a delete button at the buttom right corner). I'm getting crazy, please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a little bit of css, you can check that the `GridPane` is *actually* using all the available space in the cell, but your controls are not:

```
public MyListCell(){
    ... 
    _myComponent.setStyle("-fx-border-color: black;");
}
```

So you need to select the column you want to take all the available space, and force it to use it.

Let's say you have one `Label` in the first cell, and one `Button` in the second, that should be aligned to the right. All you need to do is create a new `ColumnConstraints` for the second column of the grid, and set it to grow always and align the content to the right:

```
private final Label label = new Label();
private final Button button = new Button("Click");

public MyListCell(){
    _myComponent.add(label, 0, 0);
    ColumnConstraints c1 = new ColumnConstraints();

    _myComponent.add(button, 1, 0);
    ColumnConstraints c2 = new ColumnConstraints();
    c2.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
    GridPane.setHalignment(button, HPos.RIGHT);

    _myComponent.getColumnConstraints().addAll(c1,c2);
}
```

And you will have your custom list cell:

[image: Custom ListCell]

Comment: Thank you so much! You saved me hours (or days)! Do you know how to  remove the margin now (so there is no mpadding/margin? Sry I am a JavaFX newbie :)

Comment: The default style for cells is defined on modena.css: `.list-cell { -fx-padding: 0.25em 0.583em 0.25em 0.583em; }`. So you just need to override it, by setting `setStyle("-fx-padding: 0;");` on the cell constructor.