# Multiple labels and images in listview javafx

Tags: java, sqlite, javafx

I want to create listView item with multiple labels and images. I created a cell class:

```
public class Cell extends ListCell<String> {
private HBox hBox;
private Label description;
private Pane pane;
private ImageView imageView;
private Image deleteImage;
private JFXButton delete;

public Cell() {
    super();
    this.hBox = new HBox();
    this.description = new Label();
    this.pane = new Pane();
    this.delete = new JFXButton("delete");

    this.hBox.getChildren().addAll(description, pane, delete);
    HBox.setHgrow(pane, Priority.ALWAYS);
    delete.setOnAction(event -> getListView().getItems().remove(getItem()));
}

@Override
protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);
    setText(null);
    setGraphic(null);

    if (item != null && !empty) {
        description.setText(item);
        setGraphic(hBox);
    }
}
```

This is part of my controller code:

```
 void addToShopCart(ActionEvent event) {
    Image partImage = selectedPart.getPicture();
    shopListView.getItems().addAll(selectedPart.getDescription());
    shopListView.setCellFactory(param -> new Cell(partImage));
}
```

selectedpart my custom class which has an image.
But now I have no idea how to send texts to these labels, because updateItem() method gets only one String. And about image, I want to set different image to each item seperately. I tried to send to constructor, but then all images are the same. I am using MVC and I can also work with code.

Comment: Only after posting my answer I have noticed this very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34838341/javafx-custom-cell-factory-with-custom-objects  . Worth having a look (and possibly marking as duplicate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your list items are more than just strings, and so your model should be a more specialized class. Depending on how complex it is, you may even want to use a `TableView`, but for now lets assume you only have a name and an image and wish to use a `ListView`.

First you need a class describing the items in the list - presumably they are "products" (as it is a shopping list) and have a description and an image:

```
class Product {
    final StringProperty description = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "description"); 
    final StringProperty image = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "image"); 

    // add getters, property-getters and setters...
}
```

Next, define your `Cell` class as extending `ListCell<Product>` - this will mean the `item` property will be of type `Product`, as should be the type of the `item` argument to the `updateItem` method.
Now whenever an item is updated/changed you can change both the decription and the image:

```
@Override
protected void updateItem(Product item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);
    setText(null);
    setGraphic(null);

    if (item != null && !empty) {
        description.setText(item.getDescription());
        imageView.setImage(...);
        setGraphic(hBox);
    }
}
```

When adding an item, create a new `Product` instance with the appropriate description and image and add it to the list. 
Note that there is no need to call `setCellFactory` every time an item is added - it should be called once during initialization (hypothetically there may be reasons to change the cell factory after it has been set, but this is not a common practice and is not needed in your case).

Note: loading images may be slow (depending on image size), so you may want to cache or pre-load the actual `Image` objects. You could also use the same `Image` object in multiple `ImageView` instances, so if multiple products use the same image this may also be beneficial.

Comment: You should also set the `ImageView.image` property to `null` to allow the garbage collector to claim the image instance, if it's no longer referenced somewhere else. Furthermore using `fitHeight` and `fitWidth` would probably be beneficial. *"(hypothetically there may be reasons to change the cell factory after it has been set, but this is not a common practice and is not needed in your case"* This will not work. Already created cells are not recreated, if you swap the factory. This would lead to diffent cell implementations without control over the use...

Comment: @fabian My point was you should almost never call `setCellFactory` more than once, although it may in some very rare cases be desirable, which may be why doing so doesn't raise an exception...  I can't think of a good reason at hand, but I also can't say for sure there aren't any.

Comment: Thank you for answer. The link you gave couldn't help. But your answer could. One more question: can I create FXML file to listItem and use it inside the Cell class?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19588029/customize-listview-in-javafx-with-fxml