# Generate groups of TextFields and output fields

Tags: java, input, javafx-8

I am writing a program to generate a log file using javafx fxml. Is it possible to generate a group of text fields that are associated by instrument.
Example:
Model:
Sn:   Tg:
Gas:

I need to gather this information for each instrument but some places have 5 units some only have 1. I am looking to have the fields generate from user input for how many they need.
Is this something I can do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ListView or TableView and custom cell factory with custom objects. Check these posts for more info -[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19588029/customize-listview-in-javafx-with-fxml) -[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34838341/javafx-custom-cell-factory-with-custom-objects)