# Issue while Populating ComboBox with Objects from ObservableList

Tags: java, oop, javafx, combobox, javafx-8

im trying to populate a combobox with objects from Observable List, But in ComboBox it shows me something else.

Code:

```
    @FXML
    private ComboBox<Veturat> box;
ObservableList<Veturat> lista = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

public void addToComboBox() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        box.getItems().clear();
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://**.***.**.***/*****";
        String user = "******";
        String pass = "***********";
        connect = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
        Statement statement;
        String sql = "Select * from veturattable";
        statement = connect.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);

        while(rs.next())
        {
            int id = rs.getInt("id");
            String vetura = rs.getString("vetura");
            String modeli = rs.getString("modeli");
            int km = rs.getInt("km");
            double qmimi = rs.getDouble("qmimi");
            String ngjyra = rs.getString("ngjyra");
            String targa = rs.getString("targa");

            veturat = new Veturat(id,vetura,modeli,km,qmimi,ngjyra,targa);
            lista.add(veturat);
        }

        box.getItems().addAll(lista);
        rs.close();
        connect.close();
    }
```

And here's what it looks in ComboBox:

[image]

Can someone please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that i didnt Override toString() method in Veturat class.

Comment: This works but there are much better solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10699655/combo-box-key-value-pair-in-javafx-2